# jquery slider issue with mozilla

Tags: php, google-chrome, jquery-ui, slider, mozilla

I am using jquery slider as a price range for selecting min to max range.

When I slide, it submits the form, and fetching records between that range.

But after post request, both sliders are set to 0 and so proper records are not getting fetched.

But, it works fine with Chrome.

Below is the code:

```
$( "#price-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    values: [ value1, value2 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {

        $('#min').val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $('#max').val(ui.values[ 1 ]);

        $('#order').val($("#price").val());
        $('#filter-form').submit();

    }
});
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: check with firebug to look errors?

Comment: Where are `value1` and `value2` coming from in your code?

Comment: Better yet, create a fiddle demonstrating your problem...

Comment: What is handling the form when it's submitted? Does the form handler or your script set the `min` and `max` in JavaScript somewhere before the slider is init'd?

Answer (score 0):

if it's running ok in other browsers you can use timers and manuplate the min and max values accordingly .

```
  $( "#price-range" ).slider({
range: true,
min: min,
max: max,
values: [ value1, value2 ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {

    $('#min').val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    $('#max').val(ui.values[ 1 ]);

    $('#order').val($("#price").val());
      // you may use the timer over here and submit the form only 
   //once not every time.. Last submution would be ok but dont forget to clear timer on previous slidings..
    $('#filter-form').submit();

}
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do a POST of your form the page itself is reloaded. The problem seems to be before the code block you posted.
Take a look at the Generation of the min and max variables.